# Proof involving Poisson Random Measure

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, poisson-distribution

Let $M$ be a Poisson Random Measure (PRM) having an intensity $\rho$. Let $g$ be a measurable function and non-negative. And then let's denote $M(g)$ as the integral with respect to $M$.

How can we show
$$E(M(g)M(f)) = \rho(gf) + \rho(g)\rho(f)$$

My intuition is that we can use the laplace functional of $M$ to show this but I'm having trouble in how to use it?

Comment: Do you know that the statement holds for $f=g$? (It's essentially Itô's isometry...)

Comment: Hint: Can you show the identity when $f$ and $g$ are step functions adapted to the same partition of the space? Say, $$f=\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\mathbf 1_{A_k}\qquad g=\sum_{k=1}^nv_k\mathbf 1_{A_k}$$ for some disjoint $(A_k)$.

Comment: I'm having trouble showing the identity. But assuming we can show the identity. Would you then take the limit as n approached infinity? Essentially approximating the full space with step functions.